# Append data to existing pytables table

Tags: python, pytables

I am new to PyTables and implemented a few basic techniques of inserting and retrieving data from a table in Pytables. However, I am not sure about how to insert data in an existing table of PyTables because all I read/get in the [tutorial](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html#creating-a-pytables-file-from-scratch) is creating a new table (using `h5file.createTable()` method). Here is the basic code that tutorial has about inserting data into PytTables table created from scratch:

```
h5file = openFile("tutorial1.h5", mode = "w", title = "Test file")
group = h5file.createGroup("/", 'detector', 'Detector information')
table = h5file.createTable(group, 'readout', Particle, "Readout example")

for i in xrange(10):
    particle['name']  = 'Particle: %6d' % (i)
    particle['TDCcount'] = i % 256
    particle['ADCcount'] = (i * 256) % (1 << 16)
    particle['grid_i'] = i
    particle['grid_j'] = 10 - i
    particle['pressure'] = float(i*i)
    particle['energy'] = float(particle['pressure'] ** 4)
    particle['idnumber'] = i * (2 ** 34)
    # Insert a new particle record
    particle.append()

    table.flush()
```

P.S. There is one [place](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/tutorials.html#appending-data-to-an-existing-table) in this tutorial that talks about appending data to an existing table, but uses the table that was created from scratch and basically gives no idea about selecting pre-existing table for appending data. Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

You need open your file in append mode `"a"`. Also do not create the group and table again. This appends another 10 rows:

```
import tables


class Particle(tables.IsDescription):
    name      = tables.StringCol(16)   # 16-character String
    idnumber  = tables.Int64Col()      # Signed 64-bit integer
    ADCcount  = tables.UInt16Col()     # Unsigned short integer
    TDCcount  = tables.UInt8Col()      # unsigned byte
    grid_i    = tables.Int32Col()      # 32-bit integer
    grid_j    = tables.Int32Col()      # 32-bit integer
    pressure  = tables.Float32Col()    # float  (single-precision)
    energy    = tables.Float64Col()    # double (double-precision)

h5file = tables.openFile("tutorial1.h5", mode = "a")
table = h5file.root.detector.readout

particle = table.row

for i in range(10, 20):
    particle['name']  = 'Particle: %6d' % (i)
    particle['TDCcount'] = i % 256
    particle['ADCcount'] = (i * 256) % (1 << 16)
    particle['grid_i'] = i
    particle['grid_j'] = 10 - i
    particle['pressure'] = float(i*i)
    particle['energy'] = float(particle['pressure'] ** 4)
    particle['idnumber'] = i * (2 ** 34)
    # Insert a new particle record
    particle.append()

h5file.close()
```

Comment: @khan Any success with this solution?

Comment: Thanks @Mike, it worked for me perfectly on Python 3.5 (with `range` instead of `xrange`) and should be marked as an answer. I slightly modified the example to create the group and the table if they are missing: https://gist.github.com/berezovskyi/10004d5fcf00a3d4477e